# KOTLIN Adjust fragment scrollview when keyboard displays

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a form in a scrollview that needs to scroll vertically as to display the rest of the form when the keyboard is displayed.

I've added this to the manifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
```

Fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBlack"
    tools:context=".ui.main.ConnectFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

          //My form
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment.kt

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
```

Do I need to add something to the onViewCreated?

Comment: With Constraintlayout always set height to 0dp for scrollview which is basically match parent and height layout inside to wrap content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest file, try adding the following to the `activity` that you want to show the keyboard when the activity starts:

> android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"

Also to make content resize when keyboard shows up you should add this code in the `onCreate` method before the `setContentView()` call

> window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)

Comment: the TS is using fragment not activity

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i'm sure about is that your form should be outside of scrollView.

everything that is inside it will react just on scroll, so will not move up when keyboard is open

Comment: I did try that earlier on and again now but it doesn't work

Comment: You want form moving up when keyboard appear right?
Could you please post all the XML code?